# How do I set min and max value of the range in Flutter chart?

Tags: flutter

[image: an]

```
return BarChart(
    seriesList,
    animate: false,
    primaryMeasureAxis: NumericAxisSpec(
        viewport: NumericExtents(10, 20)
    ),
);
```

I tried to restrict the viewport but it draws the bar outside of the viewport(I guess this is bug?)
How do I set the min and max value of the primary measure axis?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a `StaticNumericTickProviderSpec` with your own tick definitions:

```
    primaryMeasureAxis: NumericAxisSpec(
      tickProviderSpec: StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
        <TickSpec<num>>[
          TickSpec<num>(12),
          TickSpec<num>(14),
          TickSpec<num>(16),
          TickSpec<num>(18),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```