# set chart number to 100 in charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

[image]

I want to set every bar size to 100 by default it is 60. How can i do this ??

```
 List<charts.Series<BarChartModel, String>> series = [
                  charts.Series(
                    displayName: "Students Marks",
                    id: "Students Marks",
                    data: data,
                    domainFn: (BarChartModel series, _) => series.year,
                    measureFn: (BarChartModel series, _) => series.financial,
                    colorFn: (BarChartModel series, _) => series.color,
                  ),
```

Comment: Use a `StaticNumericTickProviderSpec` for the Y axis ( https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_common/latest/common/StaticNumericTickProviderSpec-class.html ) with ticks at 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 and 100. See also: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/statically_provided_ticks.html

Comment: can you provide some code snippet? I am a newbie sir... @Richard Heap

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356125/how-do-i-set-min-and-max-value-of-the-range-in-flutter-chart/61356200#61356200